# How can delete an orphaned temporary table on Mysql Innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter-table, temporary-tables

I was issuing an `alter table` statement and suddenly the server crashed. Now I can not run any `alter table` command on that table, because it shows me error 1050, and says that a table named `#sql1504d` already exists.

How can I drop that InnoDB temporary table?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the filesystem (DOS prompt, shell prompt, whatever) and delete (rm, whatever) any files starting with #sql

Also check to see how much free space exists on disk.  ALTER usually copies the entire table over.

Answer (score 1):

Move the #sql files. Usually you will find those files in the `tmp` directory. It is recommended to use [pt-online-schema](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) rather than direct alter to avoid locking.

```
mysql> show variables like '%tmp%';
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Resolving ERROR 1050 42S01 at line 1 Table already exists](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-sakilasql-ib712-already-exists/) by [Aleksandr Kuzminsky](https://twindb.com/author/akuzminsky/):

> If MySQL crashes in the middle of the ALTER process the dictionary ends up with an orphaned table.
>
> We wouldn’t care much if the temporary table name were random. But it’s not and when you run ALTER TABLE again, InnoDB picks up the same name for the temporary table. As long as a record for a table with the same name already exists in the dictionary the subsequent ALTER fails.

The MySQL documentation at [14.21.3 Troubleshooting InnoDB Data Dictionary Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html) has the official guidance. Aleksandr's alternative suggestion is:

> To get a clean dictionary for a given database we need to do following:
>
> 1. Create empty temporary database. Let it be tmp1234
> 2. Move all tables from the original database to tmp1234
> 3. Drop the original database (it’s empty by now, all tables are in tmp1234)
> 4. Create the original database again
> 5. Move all tables from the temporary database to the original one.
> 6. Drop the empty temporary database.

There are more details, including a bash script to perform the actions listed above in the linked post.